# File not found in JAR src/main/resources

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a file in src/main/resources in Spring Boot project. I load it in the runtime with following code:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("datafile.xls").getFile());
```

When I run this app from IDE everything works fine. However, when I run a JAR I get:

```
FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\myFolder\myApp.jar!\BOOT-INF\classes!\datafile.xls
```

I thought this file would be loaded from the classpath but looks like it isn't.

I'm using *mvn clean install* to generate a jar.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/datafile.xls");
```

Not sure what you want to do with the InputStream after that, see [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) and [IOUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) for ways to process afterwards.

Apache commons dependency would look like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

For spring project try this

```
ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("datafile.xls");
InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
```